# Table Doesn't exist in phpmyadmin ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apache2, phpmyadmin, database

Recently I formate my old ubuntu(14.04 LTS) Due to some reason, I copied all the data files of phpmyadmin from (/var/lib/mysql). 
In new ubuntu(16.04 LTS) I paste all that mysql data at (/var/lib/mysql).

Now I can see that data but while opening any table it gives error **Table 'database.tablename' doesn't exist**.

[image]

What can I do in this situation.

Comment: I don't think you can just copy the databases like this.. usually you use export/import because it usually contains also some system databases which depend on the OS and process and User IDs. Also did you give phpmyadmin a certain password or was it generated? Maybe you don't have access to those tables?

Comment: I made the same configuration there,Yea I tried to export all databases using CLI but it didn't worked (I was not able to use GUI). There after I copied this way.

Comment: Yeah but you can't just copy paste the mysql directory ... Look here [How to import and export mySQL databases](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/#more-184). I'm very sorry I don't know if and how your data can be restored the way you did it..

Comment: What is the output of `sudo find /var/lib/ ! -user mysql`? You may have to include `@l.d.james` for me to be sure to realize a response.